# How can I make the keyboard resign after pressing enter and/or pressing outside the keyboard area?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I have looked at a couple other answers on stackoverflow, but I can't seem to apply them to my code:

```
import UIKit
class GraphItemCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var itemNameLabel: UITextField?
@IBOutlet weak var itemDescriptionLabel: UITextField?
@IBOutlet weak var pointScore: UITextField?


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
//TextField delegate
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return false
}


override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


}
```

Comment: I used a tapgesture recognizer and did put the resignFirstResponder in there

Answer (score 0):

add a UIGestureRecognizer for tap gesture in your UITableViewCell, and call [itemNameLabel endEditing] && [itemDescriptionLabel endEditing] when cell is tapped.

Comment: @Guarav Pal, im not exactly sure how to do that. I assigned a UIGestureRecognizer to a constant : 

    let tapRec = UIGestureRecognizer()

 but I know know where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

// Dismisses keyboard when user touches outside of keyboard

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
    view.endEditing(true)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

This is what I use in my app

Comment: @ Dan L, I have this exact implementation inside of the class, inheriting from UITableViewController, connected to the tableView that the cell being edited  is inside of. Should my class inherit from anything else or could i possibly be declaring this function in the wrong place?

Comment: @KeithFrazier98 So you are calling this function within the class? Copy and paste my code into your project, replacing your function with mine and make try it again. Just a heads up, you don't call this in the GraphTermCell class, you call it in the view controller which has the tableViewController in which this cell class is controlling the table view cell. If the tableView takes up the whole view controller, the code might not work, because anywhere you touch is a tableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

Set the TextField delegate in StoryBoard.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            activeTextFiled=textField
            return activeTextFiled.resignFirstResponder();
        }

        override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
            view.endEditing(true)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a gesture recognizer to your `UITableView` and then call `endEditing(true)` method if user taps on your tableview

Answer (score -1):

First in textFieldShouldReturn return true, return false means you are denying to stop editing.
Second for dismissing keyboard when pressed outside inside touchesbegin write

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```